# Uneven Lighting on Faces (Cycles)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, faces, edges, lighting

I've a Toon Link model here. His mouth is a separate object from his face which unfortunately is an issue.
[image: Link Mouthless]

I'm trying to make a render of this model with lamps in Cycles, but the mouth doesn't "blend in" with the rest of his face like it should and does in games.
[image: Link Render 1]

I tried EdgeSplit in the modifiers and that sort of helps, but the lighting is still a problem.
[image: EdgeSplit]

[image: Render]

[Here's a link to the model](https://www.models-resource.com/download/24242/)

Any help and tips would be appreciated! If more information is needed just say the word and I'll edit the post, etc.

Comment: Your model has smooth shading so if there's a break in the mesh, the Blender has no way smoothly transition from the face to the mouth mesh, thus the hard transition. Why don't you make a single mesh of the face and mouth?

Comment: Instead of using different pieces use a single connected mesh and do the eyes, lips etc as textures. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46424/add-a-transparent-image-on-top-of-a-material

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blend4web has a tool called Normal Editor. It has a feature, that may help.

It makes custom vertex normals based on nearest vertexes:

[image]

After this operation blender creates custom vertex normals, and if you change something in geometry normals will not update, until you not delete custom normals. To delete them goto mesh settings and click this button:

[image]